# Rounding UIImage method doesn't work?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, drawing

With this method, whatever I enter for the `CGFloat` parameter, `0`, `1`, or even `100`. My `UIImage` always had a corner that is rounded even if I set the parameter to `0`. My `UIImageView` which the `UIImage` is in, is set to Scale To Fill if that makes any difference.

Anyway is there anything wrong with this method?

```
    //Rounded UIImage
- (UIImage*)roundCorneredImage: (UIImage*)orig radius:(CGFloat) r {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(orig.size, NO, 0);
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, orig.size} 
                                cornerRadius:r] addClip];
    [orig drawInRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, orig.size}];
    UIImage* result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your method just works fine. I tried in my environment. So, error should reside somewhere outside of the code snippet. Are you sure you are using the returned image for UIImageView?

Comment: Yes because otherwise my uiimageview would have no image in it. But it is odd because even if I use 0 my images are still rounded!

Comment: I am shooting in the dark, but is there a possibility that you have accidentally applied cornerRadius to your UIImageView's layer? Exact same code snippet as yours works perfectly as intended in my environment.